# Echoing one wide character in the current locale encoding from stdin back to the stdout

Tags: c, iconv, widechar

The following simple code is supposed to read one wide char from stdin and echo it back to stdout, except that it dies of `SIGSEGV` on the `iconv()` call. The question is – what's wrong with the code?

```
#include <unistd.h>   /* STDIN_FILENO */
#include <locale.h>   /* LC_ALL, setlocale() */
#include <langinfo.h> /* nl_langinfo(), CODESET */
#include <wchar.h>    /* wchar_t, putwchar() */
#include <iconv.h>    /* iconv_t, iconv_open(), iconv(), iconv_close() */
#include <stdlib.h>   /* malloc(), EXIT_SUCCESS */

int main(void) {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "");                                            // We initialize the locale
  iconv_t converter = iconv_open("WCHAR_T", nl_langinfo(CODESET));  // We initialize a converter
  wchar_t out;                                                      // We allocate memory for one wide char on stack
  wchar_t* pOut = &out;
  size_t outLeft = sizeof(wchar_t); 

  while(outLeft > 0) {                                              // Until we've read one wide char...
    char in;                                                        // We allocate memory for one byte on stack
    char* pIn=&in;
    size_t inLeft = 1;

    if(read(STDIN_FILENO, pIn, 1) == 0) break;                      // We read one byte from stdin to the buffer
    iconv(&converter, &pIn, &inLeft, (char**)&pOut, &outLeft);      // We feed the byte to the converter
  }

  iconv_close(converter);                                           // We deinitialize a converter
  putwchar(out);                                                    // We echo the wide char back to stdout
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

***UPDATE:*** After the following update based on @gsg's answer:

```
iconv(converter, &pIn, &inLeft, &pOut, &outLeft);
```

the code doesn't throw SIGSEGV anymore, but `out == L'\n'` for any non-ASCII input.

Comment: Given my answer below, it might be useful to share the compiler you are using as well as the system you are trying to compile for.

Comment: You should really be checking the results of `iconv_open` and `iconv`, by the way. In particular, you want to know if `iconv` returns `E2BIG` or `EINVAL`.

Comment: I took a bit of a look: I think you are running into trouble with `wprintf`, which expects `stdin` to be wide-character oriented (see `fwide(3)` for more info). You could try just printing the wchar_t with `printf("%lc\n")`, or read the man pages to see what you need to do for `wprintf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The signature of `iconv` is

```
size_t iconv(iconv_t cd,
             char **inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft,
             char **outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
```

But you call it with a first argument of pointer to `iconv_t`:

```
iconv(&converter, &pIn, &inLeft, (char**)&pOut, &outLeft);
```

Which should be

```
iconv(converter, &pIn, &inLeft, (char**)&pOut, &outLeft);
```

An interesting question is why a warning is not generated. For that, let's look at the definition in `iconv.h`:

```
/* Identifier for conversion method from one codeset to another.  */
typedef void *iconv_t;
```

That's an... unfortunate choice.

I would program this a bit differently:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <iconv.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(void)
{
    iconv_t converter;
    char input[8]; /* enough space for a multibyte char */
    wchar_t output[8];
    char *pinput = input;
    char *poutput = (char *)&output[0];
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    size_t error;
    size_t input_bytes_left, output_bytes_left;

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    converter = iconv_open("WCHAR_T", nl_langinfo(CODESET));
    if (converter == (iconv_t)-1)
        err(2, "failed to alloc conv_t");

    bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, input, sizeof input);
    if (bytes_read <= 0)
        err(2, "bad read");
    input_bytes_left = bytes_read;
    output_bytes_left = sizeof output;

    error = iconv(converter,
                  &pinput, &input_bytes_left,
                  &poutput, &output_bytes_left);
    if (error == (size_t)-1)
        err(2, "failed conversion");

    printf("%lc\n", output[0]);

    iconv_close(converter);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. I'm just curious – why an 8 bytes worth of a buffer per a wide character? Are there any > 4-byte wide character encodings I'm not aware of?

Comment: The 8 is just "enough, plus a bit". I don't know what the longest character encoding is, but I'm pretty sure it isn't that large. In fact arguably `input` is the wrong type: it should be a large enough array of whatever the suitable character type for the current locale is.

Comment: I see – thanks, this is a big help. Now I'm just curious what to do if I'd like to retrieve the input wchar_t by wchar_t (not just the first wide character – imagine a wide character-buffered read(2)). Any idea on how to achieve that? I could convert the entirety of 8 bytes into `wchar_t output1[8];` and then convert just 1, 2, 3..., 8 bytes of the same sequence into `wchar_t output2[8];` until `output1[0] == output2[0]`, but there must be a less brute-force way of ascertaining where the first wide character ends / next wide character begins in the input char buffer.

Comment: I would just convert the whole lot and then dole out the converted `wchar_t`s one at a time. If it really had to be done one char at a time... uh, I'm not sure how you would do that (for any arbitrary locale).

Comment: It is often the case that you just can't fit the entire thing in a buffer, be it a large file or a stream of data, and need to process it sequentially. What do you do then to ensure the final bytes of one piece and the initial bytes of another aren't just rubbish values representing a wide char cut in half?

Comment: If `iconv` encounters an incomplete byte sequence, it will leave the appropriate pointers pointing at the beginning of the sequence and return `(size_t)-1`. You can check for this condition and copy the remaining characters to start of the input buffer before doing the next `read`.

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert, but here's an example that follows what you seem to be trying to do:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/iconv-Examples.html

From the website:

> The example also shows the problem of using wide character strings
>   with iconv. As explained in the description of the iconv function
>   above, the function always takes a pointer to a char array and the
>   available space is measured in bytes. In the example, the output
>   buffer is a wide character buffer; therefore, we use a local variable
>   wrptr of type char *, which is used in the iconv calls.
>
> This looks rather innocent but can lead to problems on platforms that
>   have tight restriction on alignment. Therefore the caller of iconv has
>   to make sure that the pointers passed are suitable for access of
>   characters from the appropriate character set. Since, in the above
>   case, the input parameter to the function is a wchar_t pointer, this
>   is the case (unless the user violates alignment when computing the
>   parameter). But in other situations, especially when writing generic
>   functions where one does not know what type of character set one uses
>   and, therefore, treats text as a sequence of bytes, it might become
>   tricky.

Essentially, there are issues with alignment with iconv.  In fact, there have been a few bugs listed regarding this very issue:

http://lists.debian.org/debian-glibc/2007/02/msg00043.html

Hope that this at least gets you started.  I'd try using a char* instead of a wchar_t* for pOut, as shown in the example.

Comment: The alignment doesn't really seem to be the issue here, since I'm being sent SIGSEGV, not SIGBUS. Also, `wchar_t out; char* pOut = (char*)&out;` doesn't make any difference.